# How to create designer/editor as a web application to design pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, designer

I've a project where i need to allow users to design their own pages for their application. So i want to create a designer/editor using ASP.NET/C# or silverlight or using anyother MS technologies. The designer should have the following features

1. Drag and drop controls
2. Move the controls in the designer to
   position it
3. Preview mode/Source Mode
4. Property Window for Controls with specific properties

I've not any designer as a hosted application. I basically want to create something similar to visual studio designer as a web app. Any insights on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight fits perfectly for that.

Drag and Drop is possible too.

So if your user is fine with installing Silverlight it's the best way, in my opinion.

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Can you provide me some pointers on that? Some links or books?

Comment: I really like this Tutorial:
http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/

You can find a lot of additional controls for silverlight in the Silverlight Toolkit: (like Drag and Drop)
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/